# How to make DropDownList items grouped by category

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList whose values i want to group by category.

What are the best practices and maybe some code samples that show proper submission of form in ASP.NET MVC 3 that contains options under different categories/groups.

**Sample**

[image]

In the example above, i want the category to be collapsible and not display a radio button. Also when clicked, the category should expand to display the available radio button options under that category that allow selection of only one option. I'm not interested in tracking the value of the category, what i want to get when the form is submitted is the value of the selected option under a parent category.

Has any one done some thing similar or related in MVC 3 & jQuery?

Comment: There is some basic support for grouped dropdown's in MVC 5. [Refer example](http://www.kashyapas.com/2014/06/09/html-ldquooptgrouprdquo-support-in-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc-5-2/) but `<select>` controls are rendered by the browser based on the operating system, not the html so you have very little control. You would need to create your own html helper to render the html you want and create a jquery plugin to handle events. I've written [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768069/MVC-Custom-Select-Control) that explains how you could go about doing this.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like that using the  in HTML.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Parent 1">
    <option value="1">sub category 1</option>
    <option value="2">sub category 2</option>   
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Parent 2">
    <option value="3">sub category 1</option>
    <option value="4">sub category 2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Replace the data with your modal data.